# Convert a String (with reserved characters) to Date in Java

Tags: java, date

I want to convert a `String` (with reserved characters) to `Date` in Java

I have a string with some reserved characters in it. I am getting it from some source. Also I get the format of it from the same source. I tried to convert that string to a date but I was unable to.

The date I get:

```
{ts '2021-03-24 12:52:38.933'}
```

The format I get:

```
'{ts' ''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss{.SSS}[Z]'''}'
```

I tried with the sample code snippet but since `{}` are reserved characters and also ts is an invalid character for parsing, I am unable to parse it. Please help with how I can solve this.

Obviously I can do some string manipulation and convert it to a format I want but I don't want to do that.

```java
String dateInString = "{ts '2021-03-24 12:52:38.933'}";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("{ts' ''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss{.SSS}[Z]'''}", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `'` with another `'`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateInString = "{ts '2021-03-24 12:52:38.933'}";
        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("'{ts '''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'''}'", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = parser.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed Mar 24 12:52:38 GMT 2021
2021-03-24T12:52:38.933
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YHt5nc)

Note that the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateInString = "{ts '2021-03-24 12:52:38.933'}";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'{ts '''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'''}'", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, parser);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-24T12:52:38.933
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2mbN92)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response. The format i get from the source is '{ts' ''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss{.SSS}[Z]'''}' and you have used '{ts '''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'''}' so should i leave {.SSS}[Z] blindly ?

Comment: @harikrishna - The format should match the date-time string. The format that you are getting is not correct for the given date-time string.